# use 802.11p in my protocol in ns2.35

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ns2, 802.11p

When I use from 802.11p  In the protocol I have designed, I encounter a problem that it is sent this beacon protocol but no beacon is received,
but when using 802.11 this routine is executed correctly, What is the cause of this?

Someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: Please add more information about what you have tried so far, and in what way it failed.

Comment: @Rachel 5 : Some more information here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/2tcw3CuO2Ao **→** `Desktop.zip` → the simulation = `mobile.tcl` → → The unknown protocol `CLUSTER` is used in the file.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, This is a clustering protocol that I have designed for  vehicular ad hoc network